# asked for ten dollars

Tags: meaning, verbs, time

a. He asked me for ten dollars for using his calculator for an hour.

b. He asked me for ten dollars to use his calculator for an hour.

c. He asked ten dollars for using his calculator for an hour.

d. He asked ten dollars to use his calculator for an hour.

Which could be used if the 'asking' was done **after** the calculator was used?

Which could be used if the 'asking' was done **before** the calculator was used?

Which could be used if the 'asking' was done but the deal was refused and the calculator was not used at all?

Comment: Are you asking for a sentence that makes perfectly clear that you have already used the calculator and that you were not aware  he would want money from you until he asked you for it? Or is your question about whether non-finite forms (using, to use) can have some temporal meaning? Even the nominal form in **for using** doesn't unambiguously identify the use as having already happened.

Comment: Both forms with **using** work for an after-the-fact demand for the charge. They do not define that it was afterwards, though.

Comment: All abcd could be used before, after and if the deal was refused.

Comment: To me "He asked me for ten dollars to use his calculator for an hour" implies it's before the calculator is used (maybe because it suggests negotiation before doing something, rather than imposing a charge afterwards). Although "He charged me ten dollars to use his calculator for an hour" could be before or after. I don't know if you'll get a firm answer or if this is a matter of opinion and expectation.